# How to sort a list with respect to the its closeness it is to a given number?

Tags: python

I want to sort a list based on how close a number in the list is to a given number. So for example:

```
target_list = [1,2,8,20]
number = 4
```

then probably sorted list is `[2,1,8,20]` since:

```
   4-2 = 2
   4-1 = 3
 |4-8| = 4
|4-20| = 16
```

In case of collision, I don't really care which one comes first but then I am trying to sort the list on the basis of this distance metric.
What is the best (and pythonic) way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `key` parameter of the `sorted` function

```
>>> target_list = [1,2,8,20]
>>> sorted(target_list, key=lambda x: abs(4-x))
[2, 1, 8, 20]
```

Or if you want to sort it in place, even the list `sort` method accepts a `key`.

```
>>> target_list.sort(key=lambda x: abs(4-x))
>>> target_list
[2, 1, 8, 20]
```

Comment: the lambda bugs me. anyone got a nice oneline solution without? `sorted(target_list, key=partial(operator.add, -number))` obviously misses the `abs()` :(

Comment: @ch3ka It may be achieve with using [`functional` module](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/howto/functional.html#the-functional-module) by composing `operator.add` and `abs`.

Comment: @ch3ka But I think `lambda` would look better! Raymond Hettinger recently wrote about all those `partial`s: https://twitter.com/#!/raymondh/status/183686911112646657

Comment: don't get me wrong, ovgolovin. I *love* lambda. But it kinda bugs me, that this simple statement cannot be done simply without.

Answer (score 4):

```
sorted(target_list, key=lambda k: abs(k - 4))
```

Or to sort the list in place:

```
target_list.sort(key=lambda k: abs(k - 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> target_list.sort(key=lambda x: abs(number-x))
>>> target_list
[2, 1, 8, 20]
```